# Angular.js trigger another directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a sort of generic toggle feature between directives, where one directive which contains a template does not render, until an event occurs from another directive.  Any suggestions on how to link this together?

Thanks!

Comment: You should provide some code!

Comment: numerous ways to achieve this....some detail would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this.

#### A

Using events (but be careful, when used exessively, especially for interaction between directives, you can get lost easily! This is why I didnt create a http://plnkr.co for it, even worse:

#### code A is untested!

*so pls edit this in case of errors*

1. Use `$rootScope.$on('myEvent', function(e, eargs) {...})` on the
       master directive.
2. dispatch the event from some directive:
       `$rootScope.$broadcast('myEvent', {foo: 'bar'})`.
3. remember to inject `$rootScope` in both directives.

```
angular.module('masterDirective', [])
  .directive('masterDirective', function ($rootScope, $compile /**injects here*/) {
    var templ = '<p ng-bind="someVar"></p>';
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {},
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.someVar = "I am a template and I was born and visible to the world, because slaveDirective send me an event to do so.";
        $rootScope.$on('myEvent', function(e, eArgs) {
          // eArgs.myVar will be 'Jackson';
          element.append($compile(templ)(scope));
        });
      }
    }
  });

angular.module('slaveDirective', [])
  .directive('slaveDirective', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {},
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('myEvent', {myArg: 'Jackson'});
      }
    }
  });
```

---

#### B

Using a "shared controller" is the cleaner, but more complicated way. This approach is more strongly typed, you express the workflow and once it works, it is not as easy to break.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/WaqKzP

1. Use a controller on your master directive: `controller(scope,element,attrs) {...}`
2. require your masterDirective in slave directive: `require: 'myMasterDirective'`
3. the controller of the master directive is the fourth parameter of your slave's link function (because you required it), you can call a function to let the master include the template.

```html
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <button ng-click="includeSlave=true">include slave directive</button>
  <master-directive>
    <div ng-if="includeSlave==true">
      <slave-directive></slave-directive>
    </div>
  </master-directive>
</body>
```

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('masterDirective', function ($rootScope, $compile /**injects here*/) {
    var templ = '<p ng-bind="someVar"></p>';
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {
            return {
                slaveLink: function() {
                    $element.append($compile(templ)($scope));
                }
            }
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.someVar = "I am a template and I was born and visible to the world, because slaveDirective called a function on myself to do so.";
        }
    };
})

.directive('slaveDirective', function () {
    return {
        require: '^masterDirective',
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, myMasterController) {
            myMasterController.slaveLink();
        }
    };
});
```