# Angular run directive of paginated elements on page change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

This is going to sound complicated but, i hope someone here is more experienced than me and can sort through what follows without much difficulty.

To keep this in perspective this is all related to a pagination section like so: There's a controller that pulls some initial data objects from a test page via an ajax request. Those data objects pertain to each "puppy block" - they fill the the "puppy-block" template, of the puppy block directive, with the correct data.

The blocks are displayed using an ng-repeat (repeating for the number of data objects pulled) - this represents a page.

The pagination is independent and just modifies the controller data via different ajax requests.

I have this here `ng-repeat`:

```
<div class="puppiesContainer" ng-repeat="p in puppies track by $index">
    <puppy-block></puppy-block>
</div>
```

It's purpose is to repeat a directive a number of times
The `<puppy-block></puppy-block>` directive template is this:

```
<div class="puppyA" preview-pup>
    <div class="clearfix puppyCover" dataPreview="{{p.dataPreview}}">
        <a ng-href="{{p.link}}"><img ng-src="{{previewData[currentPosition]}}" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, there is another directive called `preview-pup` on every element.
The code for that directive is this:

```
obApp.directive('previewPup', ['$timeout',function($timeout){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, el, attr){
        //some code that needs to run often
    }
}
}]);
```

My pagination directive changes the data of the `puppy-block` directives when moving between different pages, however i also need to trigger the link function of the `preview-pup` directive, inside each `puppy-block` directive, when the change happens. Both the pagination directive and the ng-repeat directive have a common controller from which they draw data (modify data).

My problem is that i have no idea how to manually trigger a directive's link function on an `ng-click`, for instance. How may i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, found a solution:

Inject `$routeScope` into your controller and the directive you want to trigger a change in.
Use that to notify the child directive of a change in the parent controller. For more details - in case anyone stumbles upon this question looking for something similar - [Angular.js trigger another directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167604/angular-js-trigger-another-directive)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. Removing the "track by $index" from the ng-repeat fixed the it for me. Unfortunately I don't know why yet.